How to remove all items with a duplicate from an array of objects?
i have below array of object from API response.i want to push only those object whose id is not repeating and totalTime is 0
for ex - in below JSON, object with id = 4 is repeating twice so i dont want to include
this object into new array, here id = 1 and id = 3 have totaltime is 0, than i want to push this one .
Below is my JSON
const response = [
  {  
      "id": "1",
      "oeeCalculations": {
          "others": {
              "totalTime": 0
          }
      }
  },
  {
      "id": "2",
      "oeeCalculations": {
          "others": {
              "totalTime": 744
          }
      }
  },
  {
      "id": "3",
      "oeeCalculations": {
          "others": {
              "totalTime": 0
          }
      }
  },
  {
      "id": "4",
      "oeeCalculations": {
          "others": {
              "totalTime": 0
          }
      }
  },
  {
      "id": "4",
      "oeeCalculations": {
          "others": {
              "totalTime": 744
          }
      }
  }
];

Expected output -
const newResponse = [
    {  
        "id": "1",
        "oeeCalculations": {
            "others": {
                "totalTime": 0
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "id": "3",
        "oeeCalculations": {
            "others": {
                "totalTime": 0
            }
        }
    }
];

I tried below code, but its returning unique lines only..
 const values = Object.values(
      response.reduce((a, b) => {
        if (!a[b.id]) a[b.id] = b 
          return a
       }, {})
    )


It's a different question. In the linked question, only the additional duplicate items should be removed. In this question, all items with a duplicate should be removed.

@YongShun I've downvoted this question because it's basically a "Please write the code for me" question. The OP posted an attempt, that does something different. The OP doesn't show how they tried to fix the posted code or to debug it. I can't find a specific question. I see an actual input, an expected output and unrelated code. I haven't downvoted answers and I don't know why other users did this.

Here is another way to achieve the desired result:

Generate an array of all IDs using the map() function
Remove all items which have duplicates IDs using the filter() function, with the help of the previously created ids list
Remove all items which have a totalTime other than 0 using the filter() function

const ids = response.map(item => item.id);
const result = response
  .filter(item => ids.filter(id => id === item.id).length === 1)
  .filter(item => item.oeeCalculations.others.totalTime === 0);

Demo:


const response = [
  {  
      "id": "1",
      "oeeCalculations": {
          "others": {
              "totalTime": 0
          }
      }
  },
  {
      "id": "2",
      "oeeCalculations": {
          "others": {
              "totalTime": 744
          }
      }
  },
  {
      "id": "3",
      "oeeCalculations": {
          "others": {
              "totalTime": 0
          }
      }
  },
  {
      "id": "4",
      "oeeCalculations": {
          "others": {
              "totalTime": 0
          }
      }
  },
  {
      "id": "4",
      "oeeCalculations": {
          "others": {
              "totalTime": 744
          }
      }
  }
];
const ids = response.map(item => item.id);
const result = response
  .filter(item => ids.filter(id => id === item.id).length === 1)
  .filter(item => item.oeeCalculations.others.totalTime === 0);
console.log(result);



